# Similar web framework to Grails but that uses Java not Groovy?

Tags: java, grails, groovy, web-frameworks

Are there any Java Web Frameworks that are very similar to Grails but use pure Java instead of Groovy?

I really like the look of Grails, but at this moment want to focus solely on improving my Java skills, so do not want to use Groovy.

I have looked at Spring MVC and Play Framework but I only plan to develop quite simple personal applications, which is why Grails appealed to me as these seem quite heavyweight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Play, Spring Roo and [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/) are the closest Java frameworks I know of. I don't like Spring Roo's code-generation approach, don't know much about Play, so my personal preference would be Spring Boot. It seems to be under very active development at the moment and you can use some of the nicest parts of Grails in a Spring Boot app, e.g. GSP, GORM.

Comment: What is Spring Boot exactly? It's look to me like it is a tool just a tool to make the creation of Spring applications more straight forward but no an actual Web Framework itself.

Comment: @LDM91 I think that's fairly accurate. AFAIK, it's a way to a bootstrap a Spring MVC app with a bunch of other technologies (e.g. JMS, GORM, GSP) already integrated

Comment: Oh ok, it sounds like this is the approach I'm looking for, once I've familiarised myself with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about "similar to Grails," but the most basic Java web framework is the [Servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html) and [JSP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagx.html) spec from Oracle.  If you want to get started with Java, grab that and a copy of [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) and you can get started.

Comment: JSPs/Servlets are not really a web framework, and not at all similar to Grails

Answer (score 0):

You can use pure java if you still wish to utilize the Grails framework. Since Groovy is based on java, you cam use both at the same time too if you like.

Other than this, you will probably have to look into pure Servlets combined with jsp's to achieve the same thing, but it won't be as straightforward as Grails.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/)
This will allow you to generate simple Java web applications that use a database which you can then modify.